# Get WaitHandle from Task

Tags: .net, multithreading

I have an Iterator method in which I need to use a `Task`, a `CancellationToken` and an `AutoResetEvent` to monitor the Producer process. I need to be able to Wait on any (I can't await since it is an iterator).

I used `Threading.WaitHandle.WaitAny(WaitHandle[])` and it is fine for `CancellationToken` and `AutoResetEvent` but I can't find how to get a `WaitHandle` from the Task.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to cast the `Task` to `IAsyncResult` and then you can use the `AsyncWaitHandle` property like so

```
Threading.WaitHandle.WaitAny(New Threading.WaitHandle[] {((IAsyncResult)MyTask).AsyncWaitHandle, token.WaitHandle, autoResetHandle})
```